# How to deal with a Topped redwood?

Tags: tree-care

I lost the top of a redwood in a storm. is there a best practice for encouraging a single growth?  Can a young redwood shoot from the same tree be grafted to the top?

Comment: How much of it is left?

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother with grafting.  The plant will develop one or more leaders on it's own.

Select the best one and remove the rest.  The only issue is that the leaders will not be as strongly attached as the original one was and might tear off during snow or wind storms years later.

This should still work as long the redwood is not likely to get hundreds of feet tall.